# From a custom button, how can I get the account name to pre-populate in a website search?

Tags: configuration

From a custom button, can anyone tell me how to get the account name to pre-populate in a website search?  This is where I'm trying to get to: -

http://companycheck.co.uk/search/results?SearchCompaniesForm%5Bname%5D={!Account.Name}

Custom button is on the account ojbect.

Answer (score 0):

See below for how you would set it up. This screen can be accessed from **Setup** | **Customize** | **Accounts** | **Buttons, Links, and Actions** | **New Button or Link**

[image: Custom Button]

The URL listed is the same as in your question:

```
http://companycheck.co.uk/search/results?SearchCompaniesForm%5Bname%5D={!Account.Name}
```

Comment: I have already set up the button and added it to the page layout but when I click the button it only takes me to the website it doesn't auto-populate the search field.

Comment: What search are you referring to? It appears to work for me when I do http://companycheck.co.uk/search/results?SearchCompaniesForm%5Bname%5D=MyCompany

Comment: Thanks but I added a comment yesterday to say I had it sorted, many thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

what is the issue here?
Add the button to account page layout, then it should work.